# How to get data (text and pictures) from server via http get request using a NFC Tag (NFC tools)?

Tags: nfc

On my Android phone I use NFC Tools pro and I want to do following:

- get text from my server (i.e. to show it in a popup or text-to-speech)
- get picture from my server and show it

I found the "HTTP GET" request task but couldn't find out, how to use it.
(It is similar to following post/request: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?s=21b5d890966b165096d73b83bd07cd9a&p=57083540&postcount=41).

I also can show pictures, but only those which are located on the local phone.

So the question is, how can I set up the tasks in the Android app "NFC Tools" (or maybe another app), to realize the above mentioned points?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following setting: Trigger (free) + Tasker (2.99$, if memory serves).
The basic idea is:

- Trigger will read an NFC tag which will launch a Tasker's task;

Tasker will use Net -> HTTP Get to, either:

- get html from your server and parse it to extract text data (mime type = text/xml) and save it in a variable and show it with Alert -> Flash

or:

- get your picture (mime type = image/jpeg) and save it, then show it with another task.

If you want to change the image you get each time, use a first HTTP Get task to get the picture location on your server, and a second to get the actual pic. Depending on how your server is set up, you will have to fill the fields of the tasks with the right data (this is why my answer is so general, if needed I can try to go some more deeper with my explanation). Here you can find a basic guide to the use of [HTTP Get](http://tasker.wikidot.com/http-get) and in [this comment](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/tasker/6IU97xV8lNg) on the Tasker forum the use of the two phases request to get a picture from a server.

Answer (score 0):

```
server:port
```

Server is HTTPS
Port is the site address like //www.google.com
Path - starts without the forward slash "/"

Example for image downloads

```
Server - https:
Port - api-assets.clashofclans.com
Path - badges/200/NVwKVgJpNPNfeRvB7imM_nD5kD3RVzy1kkoXwT_wrx0.png
Mime type - image/png
Output file - download/test.png
```

Example to download any type of file

```
This is excel sheet 
Server:port - https://www.clashleaders.com
Path- request-n-leave-yyclqyjl.xlsx
Mime type - xlsx
output file - download/excel.xlsx
```

Create a test task and run it where Tasker and file manager in split screen view